# Types have separate declarations of a private property mock service unit test Angular 7

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ionic-framework

I am trying to create a mockService but I am getting an error "  Types have separate declarations of a private property" , to me it seems the declaration is equal and not different but it says is not in the error.
I am doing this test in a component that has the service injected!!!
Yes, I want to test it here with the mock test.

My code for the mock service:

```
class MockDataservice {   
result: any;
constructor(private http: HttpClient){
    sendCodeToServer() {
     return this.result;
     } 
}

describe('HomePage', () => 
...
{
 ...  
beforeEach(() => { 
...
    service = new MockDataservice(http);  
    component = new HomePage(platform, service, splash, statusbar, barcode, alert, http, loading, router);
```

The original service:

```
export class DataStorageService {
    result: any;
      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      }

sendToServer(data) {
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   this.http.post(endpoindURL, data, { headers: headers })
        .toPromise().then((data) => {
          resolve(data);
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Service usage in the component:

```
export class HomePage {
barcodeScannerOptions: BarcodeScannerOptions;
    constructor(private platform: Platform, private **dataStorageService**: 
    DataStorageService,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar, private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner, public 
    alertController: AlertController,
    private http: HttpClient, private loadingController: LoadingController, 
    private router: Router) {

    this.initializeApp();

    this.barcodeScannerOptions = {
          showTorchButton: true,
          showFlipCameraButton: true
        };
      }

    function doesSomething(){
    this.dataStorageService.sendToServer(data).then((res) => {
    }
```

I get the error here  in the home.spec file, in the word service

component = new HomePage(platform, **service**, splash, statusbar,
barcode, alert, http, loading, router);

and the error is

> MockDataservice is not assignable to parameter of type
>       //DataStorageService.   Types have separate declarations of a
>       private property http.ts

Comment: can you properly format your code, please?

Comment: @fjc it is now properfly formatted, can you sitll take a look?

Comment: Is there a reason you are manually instantiating the unit under test instead of letting `Testbed` do it?

Comment: Check out my answer below

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So here's the exhaustive answer what's happening. I constructed a minimal example that reproduces the behavior: [Broken example on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Dependency%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Service%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20dep%3A%20Dependency)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20doSomething()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('I%20am%20doing%20something')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MockService%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20dep%3A%20Dependency)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20doSomething()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('I%20am%20just%20pretending%20to%20do%20something')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Component%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20service%3A%20Service)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.service.doSomething()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20dependency%20%3D%20new%20Dependency()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20service%20%3D%20new%20Service(dependency)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20mockService%20%3D%20new%20MockService(dependency)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20this%20works%0D%0Aconst%20component1%20%3D%20new%20Component(service)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20this%20does%20not%20work%0D%0Aconst%20component2%20%3D%20new%20Component(mockService)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A). You can actually see the exact same error message.

What's going here? The `Component` expects an instance of the actual `Service` class in its constructor. `MockService` **is not** a `Service`. It just coincidentally has the same constructor parameters and the same method names. The compiler does not know that the two are actually compatible (i.e. implement the same interface), and therefore throws an error.

How do we fix this? Work with actual object oriented abstraction. As `Service` and `MockService` are actually interchangeable, we need to let the compiler know that. How do we do that? **By having them implement the same interface**.

We'll just define a `Service` interface. We'll have a `ConcreteService`, which contains the default behavior, and which implements `Service`. We'll also have our `MockService`, which will implement the same `Service`, but have mocked behavior: [Working example on TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Dependency%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Service%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20doSomething()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ConcreteService%20implements%20Service%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20dep%3A%20Dependency)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20doSomething()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('I%20am%20doing%20something')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MockService%20implements%20Service%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20dep%3A%20Dependency)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20doSomething()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('I%20am%20just%20pretending%20to%20do%20something')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Component%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20service%3A%20Service)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.service.doSomething()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20dependency%20%3D%20new%20Dependency()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20service%20%3D%20new%20ConcreteService(dependency)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20mockService%20%3D%20new%20MockService(dependency)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20this%20works%0D%0Aconst%20component1%20%3D%20new%20Component(service)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20this%20does%20now%2C%20too%0D%0Aconst%20component2%20%3D%20new%20Component(mockService)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A).,

Comment: thank you very much for answering my question! this helps me a lot